# ASP.NET Web API - actionContext - get actionDescriptor of other controller.action

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I'm working on some response-caching middleware for ASP.NET.
One of its features is to invalidate cache of certain action when specific action is executed.

Sparing you the details of how the cache-key logic is implemented, I'll go straight to the question.

Here is a controller with two actions:

```
public class EchoController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("api/echo/{userId}/{message}")]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Echo(
        [AttributeX] string userId,
        [AttributeX] string message,
        string queryString)
    {
        await Task.Delay(150);
        return Ok(new {Action = "Echo", UserId = userId, Message = message, QueryString = queryString});
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [Route("api/echo/dosomething")]
    [AttributeY(ActionName = "Echo")]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> DoSomethingWithAction(string userId, string message)
    {
        await Task.Delay(150);
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

`AttributeY` is an `ActionFilterAttribute` and implements the `OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)` method.

In this implementation I would like to have a list of all action parameters of **action `Echo`** filtering only those with the `AttributeX` attribute.

How could I do that?

- Reminding you that whenever action `DoSomethingWithAction` is called, then `OnActionExecuting` is called with context containing information about `DoSomethingWithAction` action, not `Echo` action.

Comment: Em just using reflection? The `HttpActionContext`, even by name, will only provide the `context` in which your filter is executing. However, you could use that to find the controller which defines the action and then find public methods with the `ActionName` on that, and then use reflection to inspect arguments from `MethodInfo`.

Comment: @zaitsman that’s not very efficient I guess ?

Comment: What makes you say that

Comment: @zaitsman I’m more of asking than saying ;). But doing this reflection for every request - that’s going to add something to the e2e latency - is it going to be significant?

Comment: You don’t have to do it for every request. You can store this information in a static `ConcurrentDictionary` so the actual reflection will only run once per process